# How can i read JSON data from online file?(python)

Tags: python, json, api

I have a site, with only JSON data. And i need to read this data with python.

So i need to know, how can i load an online JSON.

```py
import json

f = "https://api.npoint.io/7872500d7eef44a03194"

data = json.load(f)
```

So how can this work? And then how can i check internet connection errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `requests` library:

```
import requests

f = "https://api.npoint.io/7872500d7eef44a03194"
data = requests.get(f).json()

data
```

Output:

```
{'sample': 'this is only a sample'}
```

Comment: much better would be `data = resp.json()`

Comment: @buran Not sure it would be *much* better, but yes, it would definitely be more concise :) Updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use below for API calls

```
import requests

url = "https://api.npoint.io/7872500d7eef44a03194"
response = requests.request('get', url)
print(json.loads(response.text))
```

Output

```
{'sample': 'this is only a sample'}
```